# Error "nullishCoaleacingOperator" isn't currently enabled

Tags: react-native

When I tried to build my app on iOS-simulator it says:

> error:(SyntaxErorr:/Users/shubhamb/Downloads/Code/node_modules/react_native/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBar.js:
>   Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't
>   currently enabled).

I have also added the plugin in `babel.rc`.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: When I ran the command react-native run-ios the build was successful but as soon as the app started launching on ios-simulator it shows the above error. I have already added "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator" in the babelrc